# Filling an entire MenuButton with an Image

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, menuitem

I'm trying to create a WPF menu that consists out of 5 simple buttons that are filled entire with a single image. I've created the following XAML:

```
<Menu x:Name="menuMain" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItemPrint" Width="40" Height="40">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Yes.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItemClear" Width="40" Height="40">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Yes.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItemSettings" Width="40" Height="40">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Yes.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItemScanner" Width="40" Height="40">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Yes.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem x:Name="menuItemMode" Width="40" Height="40" Click="menuItemMode_Click">
        <MenuItem.Icon>
            <Image Source="Resources/Images/Yes.png" Width="40" Height="40"/>
        </MenuItem.Icon>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

But the exact result of that is shown below:
[image]

It's showing only the top left quarter of the image, and it seems to be offsetting it for some bizarre reason as well? Almost all answers on the internet involve setting the size of the picture, which I did (the .PNG size is exactly 40x40, and so are the MenuItems and Images.

I've tried changing the alignment, setting Fill to 'Stretch' and adjusting the margin, but nothing seems to help.

For the record, what I'm trying the achieve is shown below (Though preferably with a less grotesquely ugly green checkmark. You'll have to excuse my editing skills).

[image]

Comment: how big is the original image? larger or smaller than 40x40?

Comment: @d Like I mentioned, it's precisely 40x40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `Icon` attribute, use the `Header` and just set a `margin` offset.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="menuItemPrint" Width="40" Height="40">
    <MenuItem.Header>
        <Image Source="Resources/Images/Yes.png" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="-7"/>
    </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: This actually works! I'm still quite confused about why my original solution doesn't work, but thanks!

Comment: no problem! also, since you have a lot of the same properties getting set for each image, you may want to create a style that all images use. it's a bit more clean, and if you ever want to make changes you'll just need to change it in one place

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the menuitem template. This seems to work for me.

```
<Menu Height="40">
    <MenuItem Height="40" Width="40">
        <MenuItem.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="source path here" />
            </ControlTempalte>
        </MenuItem.Template>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: While this fixes the size and alignment issues, the problem with this approach is that it erases all the behavior of a proper MenuItem. For example, I no longer get a square highlighter when I mouse over for example aka the kind of behavior why I'm making this a MenuItem in the first place :(

Comment: Aw yes. I hadn't thought of that. d moncada's solution seems good though.